# How does VS Code support projects?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I come from IDEs which support the concept of "project", that is an entity which encompasses specific files (and folders) and associated configuration and are visually independent form each other. They can also usually be opened as "projects", bringing in everything which is associated to them.

The closest I could find in VS Code are **workspaces**, which seem to be folders with a `.vscode` subfolder which may contain a configuration file specific to that subfolder. They are not specifically visible within VS Code (with the ability to open them for instance)

**Is this indeed how projects are managed in VS Code?**

The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) mentions that a "project" can also be opened:

> Open a project
>
> `vscode://file/FULL/PATH/TO/PROJECT/`

but it may just be a name for "folder with a `.vscode` subfolder within"

Comment: Visual Studio Code is designed to support different languages and frameworks, some of which do not have the notion of "project" that you are describing and that some other IDEs (bound to a specific platform) do have.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extention [project-manager](https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-project-manager).

With this you can save project or open list of saved projects <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. It also says (I never used this feature) that you can turn on auto-detection of projects (vscode or git or svn).